# Conditional operator for calling a method

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, conditional-operator

I need to call a function if an condition fails and do nothing if its true.

```
$('body').click(function (e) {
    ($(this).hasClass("name")) ? return : checkforemail();
});
```

I couldn't use the return here. How to achieve this ?

Comment: why don't you use a if lol?

Comment: Why are you using the ternary operator? The statement isn't something you can assign a value to, and `return` isn't a valid value. Other than `return` use something like: `null`,`0`,`1`,etc. It doesn't entirely matter what you use as long as it's valid.

Comment: The ternary operator evaluates to an expression and expressions can't have a return statement in them , so is the error

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).hasClass("name")` will return a boolean value & also you dont need to explicitly return true. If your condition is not meet you can use `:(or)` to call the function

```
//$('body').addClass("name")
    $('body').click(function (e) {
        ($(this).hasClass("name")) ==true ? 1 : checkforemail();
    });


function checkforemail(){
alert("Hello");
}
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6r12xat/)

Note: In the jsfiddle un comment `$('body').addClass("name")`.Clicking on the body will call the function

Answer (score 0):

Use a if

```
$('body').click(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("name")) {checkforemail();}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.is()`, `AND` operator `&&`

```
!$(this).is(".name") && checkforemail();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use return statement in `ternary` !But If you desire to return statement try like below..

```
$('body').click(function (e) {
    var status = ($(this).hasClass("name")) ? true : false;
    return status;
});
```

Or not if you want only call your method

```
$('body').click(function (e) {
    if(!$(this).hasClass("name")){
            checkforemail();
    }
});
```